# Problems with PHP upload

Tags: php, upload

My code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $allowedExts = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
    $extension = end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']));
    if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
        if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 50000){
            if ($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0){
                $uploaderror = $_FILES['image']['error'];
            }else{
                $uploaderror = 'FALLBACK ERROR';
                if(file_exists('..images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'])){
                    $uploaderror = 'The file <strong>'.$_FILES['image']['name'].'</strong> already exists in the images directory.';
                }else{
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '..images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
                    $uploadsuccess = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                }
            }
        }else{$uploaderror = 'The image is too large.';}
    }else{$uploaderror = 'Only images (.jpg, .png, and .gif) are allowed.';}
}else{$uploaderror = 'No attempt';}
```

The output:
`$uploaderror` returns `FALLBACK ERROR` and `$uploadsuccess` is not set. The file is NOT appearing in the speicifed directory and I cannot find it on the server. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, that is some noisy code.

Comment: What does your form look like? In some places you use `$_FILES['image']` and others you use `$_FILES['file']`

Comment: this format is wrong: `'..images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']` your missing a `/` after the `..`

Comment: what @RyanNaddy said, and you have to unset the `$uploaderror` in the `else` part where `move_uploaded_file` is used. Second `move_uploaded_file` returns `true` on success, here you could specify a correct approach to set the `$uploaderror` or `$uploadsuccess` variable with correct values.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There is no upload error if the script enters the `else` statement where `$uploaderror = 'FALLBACK ERROR';` is defined, see [features.file-upload.errors.php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: @dbf Sorry I misread that as `$_FILES['image']['error'] == 0`

Comment: Thanks, all! @MichaelBerkowski I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `/` after the `..` and before `images`, to fix this just change this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '..images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

to the following:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

With your code run through a terminal you would get the following response:

> ..images: No such file or directory

**Edit**

I found another spot where you forgot the `/` and that is in your `file_exists()` check.

I have cleaned up your code too, to make it more readable:

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$allowedExts = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors[] = "No attempt.";
}
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    $errors[] = "Only images (.jpg, .png, and .gif) are allowed.";
}
if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 50000){
    $errors[] = "The image is too large.";
}
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] <= 0){
    $errors[] = $_FILES['image']['error'];
}
if(file_exists('../images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $errors[] = 'The file <strong>'.$_FILES['image']['name'].'</strong> already exists in the images directory.';
}

// No errors found!
if(count($errors) == 0){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadsuccess = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using an array for errors is good, but doesn't work with `if(isset($uploaderror))`, which I use later.

Comment: you could do `if(!empty($errors))` meaning it contains errors